# Math notation to take values from a tuple

Tags: functions, notation

I have a set of tuples, let's say

$t_i = (a, b)$

Now I want to define a function $f: T \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is supposed to just divide the tuple's two values.

And I'm insecure about how to write it... This doesn't look to good:

$d(t) = \frac{a}{b}$

Comment: You can use various form of [arrow notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Arrow_notation) to specify the function ( eg. $f: T \to \mathbb{R}; (a,b) \mapsto \frac{a}{b})$. When domain/codmain is clear from context, you can use $f: (a,b) \mapsto \frac{a}{b}$ or even $(a,b) \mapsto \frac{a}{b}$ to refer to the function.

Comment: That is fine notation, except for the unnecessary $i$ subscript. You can either say $f(a,b)=\frac ab$ — or, technically, $f((a,b))=\frac ab$ — or you can say in words "if $t=(a,b)$ then we define $f(t)=\frac ab$."

Answer (score 1):

Standard notation for this would be as follows. Let $T$ be your set of tuples. Define $f:T \to \mathbb R$ by $f(a,b) = \frac a b$.